MySQL 5.7: Is it relevant/risk to have external hosts in the mysql.Hosts column if "skip-networking" is enabled?

NOTE: I am well aware our MySQL is out of date and I am pushing on this but we can't update at this time.

A couple of small questions I can't find clear responses to:

I have found that our MySQL v5.7.44 - MySQL Community Server (GPL) has a bunch of users on the "mysql" database with the "Host" field showing non local IP addresses as their "Host".
Does this cause any risk (hypothetically) while the My.cnf setting "skip-networking" is set to TRUE?
These shouldn't be here I believe and will clear them out but I wanted to understand if the "skip-networking" flag has caveats for example if the host is listed on the mysql.users table.

Some of these external IPs are old servers we used to be on back in the day, but some are not. Would this be a likely indicator for a database compromise?

On the same topic, we also have a bunch of users on the "mysql" database with the "Host" field showing the current domain name of the server, as well as a "Host" showing the current IP address of the server. Is this an issue? IS there an advantage to clearing either of these users?



If skip-networking remains active, then there is no risk. The MySQL Server will not accept any connections over TCP/IP. It will only accept local clients using the socket file on UNIX/Linux or a named pipe on Windows.
The risk is that the skip-networking option might be removed by someone else in the future. That means MySQL Server will again accept connections from clients using TCP/IP.
If the database administrator doesn't know to check for existing MySQL users in the password table, then suddenly a bunch of supposedly inactive users will be able to connect, using whatever old password had been set for those users.
If it were me, I'd take the time to drop the unneeded MySQL users. Then you don't have to worry about the risk of them becoming active again, and you don't have to worry whether your successor who takes responsibility for that MySQL Server instance knows about the risk.

Re your comment:
The only users who can connect if skip-networking is active are user@localhost.
You're not locking out any user, given that they can't connect anyway if they are user@hostname or user@ipaddress. It makes no difference if they are identified by hostname or ip address. They both use TCP/IP, and they're both locked out already. If this isn't causing a problem right now, then you're good.

I totally agree re dropping the users but many of them appear to be system generated so  I dont want to lock out genuine system created connections. I'm unclear if a Host should preferentially be the IP or the server hostname (not the domain name of the child website). Most of these connections last appear to have been edited (according to the mySQL table) several years ago, so I'm not concerned it's a present threat but would like to lock this down more than it currently is. Thanks
